# Reading a .WAV file in c and extracting frequencies from it

Tags: c++, c

I made a structure in C and read all data in dat structure using fread function,Actually i confused about that,what is actual "audio data" means original sample data?
and how can we extract frequencies from dat audio data.
And I  can successfully read that data but cant understand what  i have to do further.
Pl explain.

Comment: I think you are talking about [RIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format) files. RIFF is a container format that can contain the audio data encoded in many different ways. As such, you have to provide a decoder for each possible audio format or restrict your requirements to a small subset of RIFF files.

Comment: If you're looking to use C, do not tag the question with C++. They're not the same language.

Comment: @ Jonathon Reinhart:  hello sir,i just want the logic and technique nothing else which is almost same in c and c++ both have structure and somehow same.And sorry but we can do all programs same as C and C++.pl i respects each member,but just think abt it if you want you can give ans.And i dnt want to use any inbuild library so i posted this question it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily read a wav file , just follow this document. 
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

As for extracting frequencies from the file you would need to apply a Fourier Transform to your data , which would convert your data from Amplitude Time to Frequency time domain.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform

Comment: Thank Xeon111,I have use this link in my project to read wave file. was very help full to me.Thanks...:)

Answer (score 3):

An audio file, typically, consists of a header and "samples". The samples can be 8, 16 or 32 bit and integer or floating point. Some audio files store the audio samples in a compressed form (mp3 for example), where others store the data as "raw samples".

To analyse the frequency, you need to perform a "fourier transform", which will give you an array of "how much at this frequency". The actual fourier transform is quite complex to describe (it's certainly more than a few dozen lines).

If the samples are in integer form, you'll have to convert from integer to floating point by dividing each sample by the max value (255, 32767 or 2<sup>31</sup>-1).

Here's a package of C++ code to do FFT. There are several others out there. 
http://fftwpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: here what is the max value? and i am extracting values from .WAV files only. :)

Comment: How should I know? Could be any number of bits. Only way to tell is to read the header information in the file.

Comment: Actually i didn't understand FFT,so wants some basic or graphycal representation of it so i can learn how to calculate frequency,because i can't understand what is window size and what is "del"? etc. pl help me out

Comment: That is really a whole new question. An FFT will give you a "graphical" (well, a table) result of frequencies.

Comment: actually problem is code for DFT/FFt bcz i didn't get it.so now I want to calculate frequencies from sample data.

Comment: So, I think you should start a new question, with what you have done so far, and what exactly you're struggling with.

Comment: hey i have mentioned it in above questions also pl...:/

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example of performing the FFT. This one displays the results in a Windows GUI.

http://www.relisoft.com/Freeware/index.htm